# Error CS0433 in Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I'm absolutely desperate with this.

I wanted to change my Xamarin Forms Project from PLC to .NET Standard (v.1.5) and i made the mistake to change it in the Project options. After changing, i realised it's a bad approach and wanted to restore to PLC. After changing back i cannot build the project anymore as I'm getting 96 compile errors. Every error is saying "Error CS0344"

The type 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
 and 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'

It says that for basically every CS and XAML file i have in the project. I have no idea what to do to fix this. I searched almost the whole web for a solution and i'm clueless.

Thanks in regards for your help.

Comment: Create a new .NetStd 2.0 library project, copy/paste your code files from the old project and add the nugets/references that you were using.

Comment: When i try to create a new solution i can't choose .NetStd for some reason, it's greyed out (I'm on the newest version of VS on Mac). Also, do you have an advice how to properly copy these files? Like recreate them by hand and copy the code in?

Comment: You can copy/paste the entire file via the solution explorer, highlight the file(s), select copy, go to your other project and right click on the project (or subfolder) and paste. That simple. So the .NetStd 2.0 is disable in the dropdown? Are the other .NetStd versions enabled in that dropdown? Confused?

Comment: Ok, perfect, i'll try it with the solution explorer. No there is not a single .NetStd version that can be selected. It's completley greyed out, i can only choose PLC. Maybe it's a new bug?

Comment: right click on the solution:  `Add` / `Add New Project...` / `Multi-platform` / `Library` / `.Net Standard Library` (that is not available? greyed out? ...?) When you say latest version, what version is that as there are stable/beta/alpha channels?

Comment: Okay, i was actually trying to create a new Forms App, i didn't go to Library/.Net Standard Library before. I can create a 1.6 Project. I was just a little confused because this looks pretty different to PLC. But i can still use standard Xamarin.Forms in a project like this?

Comment: Yes, all a Forms project is a library project with the Forms package added to it... of course there is some initialization of the Forms Application but it is *just* a .Net assembly at the end of the day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173583/discussion-between-elias-johannes-and-sushihangover).